# SQL PI/SQL Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 DECLARE 
   a number(2);
  a1 int;
BEGIN 
   FOR a in 01 .. 12 LOOP 
    SET a1 =(SELECT count(*) 
FROM ECMS_ONLINE_TRANSACTION eoa
WHERE eoa.CREATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-01-01 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2021-01-01 01:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
) 
      dbms_output.put_line('value of a: ' || a); 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

**I have an error on this code I need the value of month which means a and the respective count and also in where condition the month should change according to a please someone help on this issue i am using oracle db **

Comment: You have an error, but don't tell us the error message? Is this a guessing game? On first glance: `SET` is not a PL/SQL command. You need `SELECT ... INTO ...`. Semantically though, there seem to be more issues. You are not using the month in your loop, but select the same count again and again. Then you try to put this result into a variable the value of which you don't show. (You always show 'value of 01 is 1; value of 02 is 2; ...). `a` is the perfect name for a month variable, by the way. It would certainly be my second choice after `v_month`. Same for the great variable name `a1`.

Comment: On a side note: There is no need to convert a timestamp string into a datetime with `TO_DATE`. Simply use a timestamp interval: `WHERE eoa.createtime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 01:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 01:59:59'`. Another point: this exclude the fractions of the last second of the day. Better is:  `WHERE eoa.createtime >= DATE '2021-01-01' AND eoa.createtime < DATE '2021-01-02'`.

Comment: can you please write the sql function for me as a code i have tried into but not working

Comment: This is simple: `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO a1 FROM ecms...`.

Comment: I have done that can you please help me on changing where cause according to loop mean  from a  like if a =1 means month has to be 1

Comment: Instead of keeping asking, you should improve your question by providing more information (e.g. error message you get)

Comment: i am not getting error message i need a function of changing the month according to loop

Comment: `DECLARE 
   a number(2);
  cnt number;
BEGIN 
   FOR a in 01 .. 12 LOOP 
  select count(*) 
     into cnt
     FROM ECMS_ONLINE_TRANSACTION eoa
     WHERE eoa.CREATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-01-01 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2021-01-01 01:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); 
 
     dbms_output.put_line(' month: ' || a || ' time stamp 01:00:00- 01:59:59  number of transaction :' || cnt ); 
   END LOOP; 
END;`

Comment: i need to change the month according to loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
 a number(2);
 cnt number;
BEGIN 

  FOR a in 01 .. 12 LOOP 
 
    select count(*) 
    into cnt
    FROM ECMS_ONLINE_TRANSACTION eoa
    WHERE eoa.CREATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-' || lpad(a, 2, '0') || '-01 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                     AND TO_DATE('2021-' || lpad(a, 2, '0') || '-01 01:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); 

    dbms_output.put_line(' month: ' || a || ' time stamp 01:00:00- 01:59:59  number of transaction :' || cnt ); 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

Sample data (only `createtime` column (displayed in `YYYY-MM-DD` format), as query doesn't use any other):

```
SQL> select * from ecms_online_transaction order by createtime;

CREATETIME
----------
2021-01-01
2021-02-24
2021-02-25
2021-04-13
2021-08-22
2021-08-29

6 rows selected.

SQL> set serveroutput on
```

As it seems you want to calculate number of rows **per month** (days, hours, years, ... - they don't matter), you could write such a query in the cursor and just display what it fetched):

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     FOR cur_r IN (  SELECT TO_CHAR (createtime, 'mm') month, COUNT (*) cnt
  3                       FROM ecms_online_transaction
  4                   GROUP BY TO_CHAR (createtime, 'mm')
  5                   ORDER BY TO_CHAR (createtime, 'mm'))
  6     LOOP
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
  8           'Month = ' || cur_r.month || ', count = ' || cur_r.cnt);
  9     END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /
Month = 01, count = 1
Month = 02, count = 2
Month = 04, count = 1
Month = 08, count = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```